# My app crashes when I run it without debugger

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have developed and iPad app which runs fine when I run with debugger, but when normally run from the `simulator` without debugger it crashes on the screen where `Map View Kit` is placed. I haven't initialised the `mapView`.
And why it isn't crashing when run from debugger.

Comment: have you included the frameworks in copy bundle resources and compile sources

Comment: This is not a question with or without. If crash then you must be see a crash log so post with question. So other can get to know where is an issue and what's that possible solution.

Comment: @Intellij-Shivam happy to hjelp :)

Comment: @NitinGohel read the question first... how can i see the logs of the simulator when it is not connected to the debugger and the app is working fine when I run it from the xcode directly

Comment: Having read your question, I find simulator crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/.

Comment: @cpt. Sparrow I am having the same issue, If you got the solution for the same please share it to me. Thank you

Comment: @GregoryWilsonPullyattu have you added the Framwork in copy Bundle resources and compile sources ?

Comment: Thank you it works

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue. i'm not able to debug. The application is perfectly running without any crash at run time. If I test application without any debugger the application is crashing every time. After R&D I got this answer.

Add MapKit Framework in your project -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content.